# Bootstrap Carousel does not work after next set of entries loaded

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using infinite scroll to load more entries (https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll) upon manual trigger after the first set of entries are loaded.

Each entry has a Bootstrap carousel attached to it, and with the first set of entries, these work fine. But after I click "load more" to load the additional entries, carousel does not work with the newly fetched entries.

This is what I have to trigger the Carousel into action (along with touch/swipe support)

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    (function($) {
    $('[id^="mycar"]').carousel({
        interval: 20000
    });
    $('[id^="mycar"]').swiperight(function() {  
          $(this).carousel('prev');  
    });  
    $('[id^="mycar"]').swipeleft(function() {  
          $(this).carousel('next');  
    });  
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: May want to look at binding using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Also, you may have to destroy the Carousel's data first and re-instantiate it after more entries have been added.

Comment: FWIW: http://jsfiddle.net/khgjpo6q/